# Extjs document click event

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a popover component that hides its content on document click event. My logic goes like this:

```
show : function () {
    var me = this;

    if (me.visible) {
        return;
    }


    Ext.getDoc().on('click', function handleDocClick(e) {

        if ( e.within(me.el) ) {
            return;
        }

        if (me.isVisible() && !e.within(me.divEl)) {
            me.hide();
            Ext.getDoc().un('click', handleDocClick);
        }
    });

    var cfg = me.determineLocation();       
    me.setLocation(cfg);

    me.visible = true;
},

hide : function () {
    this.visible = false;
            .........
},
```

I have problems with calling the popover component hide method. Doing so the event is left unwound effectively causing a memory leak.

I tried to change the event binding like this:

```
Ext.getDoc().on('click', Ext.bind(this.handleDocClick, this));
```

and in hide:

```
hide : function () {
    Ext.getDoc().un('click', Ext.bind(this.handleDocClick, this));
    this.visible = false;
            .........
},
```

but this didn't help much as event is not properly unwind again.

My question is how to solve the problem. The best solution would be:
in show:

```
Ext.getDoc().un('click', functionClick);
Ext.getDoc().on('click', functionClick);
```

and in hide:

```
Ext.getDoc().un('click', functionClick);
```

I can accept even a function in global scope but I'm not sure how Can I distribute params from object instance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by unwind, but it sounds like you are trying to to have this event to be executed once and then listener removed. In this case ExtJS observable API has options to include for your listener:

> single : Boolean
>
> True to add a handler to handle just the next firing of the event, and
>   then remove itself.
>   http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-on

Hope that's what you need.

Comment: this will not work properly for him because in handler function it first needs to determine where click has happened, if its clicked on wrong place then the event is ignored instead of removing the listener but single option will remove every time a click occurs anywhere in the document, which user definitely don't want :)

Comment: so why not place the listener directly on the component that needs to be hidden?